# Magento1 memory exhausted issue when trying to execute order collection

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales

I have written following code to travere through order collection but its giving me memory issue

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

foreach ($orders as $order) {....}
```

I there any suggestion on how can i access the order collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in index.php and Mage.php files of Magento:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```